# How to fix code to open files passed in the command prompt in codeblocks

Tags: c, file, command

I'm trying to pass the names of the arguments to be readen in codeblocks through set program arguments. When I open them directly, I use

```c
    FILE * file_1 = fopen("file31.ll", "r");
    FILE * file_2 = fopen("file32.ll", "r");
```

And it works, cause file31 and file32 are in the same paste as the file. However, when I create a project (and put the files inside its paste), I try to write file31.ll and file32.ll in the arguments and it doesn't work. When compilling, the program warns that the files couldn't be open because the directory wasn't found ("error opening the file : no such a file or directory"). I've also tried writing "file31" and "file32", and also copied the address in Windows like:
C:\Users...\opening_files\file31
where opening_files is the name of the project

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "LCS.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Incorret number of arguments!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //I print argc and argv to test if the arguments are being passed correctly
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        fputs(argv[i], stdout);
        printf("\n");
    }
    //They are printed correctly
    //However, when trying to open the files, the program warns that the
    //directories weren't found
    //Opening the files
    FILE * file_1 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    FILE * file_2 = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    if (file_1 == NULL || file_2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file\n");
    }
```

I tried to read some other posts about this online but I haven't understand them very well, cause I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: A better error message would help you pinoint the error.  Give the name of the file you are trying to open: `if( (file_1=fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL ) {perror(argv[2]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Comment: It prints:                                                                                                                                error opening the file : no such a file or directory

Comment: My point is that "error opening the file" is much less useful  than giving the path that was used.  Also, you need to check immediately.  If file_1 fails to open (eg permission denied), then errno will not reflect the error that occurred and the message generated by perror will not be accurate. (eg, the second fopen may succeed and set errno to 0)

Answer (score 1):

The indexing of the argv[] is incorrect. The argv[1] store the file_1 path and the argv[2] store the file_2 path.

```
FILE * file_1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FILE * file_2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made these corrections but the problem persists.

Comment: Is this also pestists if you copy the files next to your binary?

Comment: What means copying next to your binary? When I open then inside the program it works well ir "r"